# Проблема с сортировкой массива записей

Tags: pascal, pascalabc.net

Задача:
Есть информация о результатах зимней сессии на первом курсе. Данные о каждом студенте-первокурсника представлены в следующем виде:
<Фамилия>, <номер_групы>, <оцинка1>, <оцинка2>, <оцинка3>,
где первая оценка - за экзамен по высшей математике, вторая - по программированию, третья - по истории.
Составить программу, которая вводит эту информацию и печатает следующие данные:
Рейтинг студентов по убывающей успешности

```
    type info = record
        groupe: string[15];
        markMath, markProg, markHist: real;
        end;
     ser = record
       surname: string[15];
       seredn: real;
       end;
     S = array [1..10] of ser;
     register= array [1..10] of info;
var i,j,n: integer;
    MAX: real;
    A: array [1..100] of real;
    reg : register;
    sered: S;
begin
    randomize;
    repeat 
        write('Enter quantity of students: ');
        readln(n);
    until n>0;
    for i:=1 to n do
        begin 
        with reg[i] do
           begin
             with sered[i] do
               begin
                   write('Enter surname: ');
                   readln(surname);
               end;
             write('Enter groupe: ');
             readln(groupe);
             for j:=1 to 3 do
                 begin
                    if j=1
                        then begin
                              markMath:=random(101);
                              writeln('Math: ', markMath);
                              //readln(markMath);
                             end
                        else begin
                                  if j=2
                                      then 
                                        begin
                                          markProg:=random(101);
                                          writeln('Programming: ', markProg);
                                          //readln(markProg);
                                        end
                                      else 
                                        begin
                                           markHist:=random(101);
                                           writeln('History: ', markHist);
                                           //readln(markHist);
                                        end;
                             end;


                 end;
             with sered[i] do
               begin
                 seredn:=(markMath+markProg+markHist)/3;
                 writeln('Average[',i,']= ', sered[i].seredn:6:1);
               end;
            end;
        end;



  with sered [i] do
   begin
       for j:=1 to N-1 do
          for i:=1 to N-j do
              if sered[i].seredn < sered[i+1].seredn 
                  then begin
                      swap(sered[i].seredn,sered[i+1].seredn);
                   end;
   end;

  for i:=1 to n do
      writeln(sered[i].seredn);
 for i:=1 to n do
        begin 
          with sered[i] do
             writeln(i,' - ',sered[i].seredn,'famil -  ', sered[i].surname);
        end;
end.
```

Получилось отсортировать средние значения, но есть проблема: Как отсортировать фамилии?

Comment: "Как отсортировать фамилии?" - имеется ввиду, что при равном среднем балле фамилии должны быть по алфавиту?

Comment: Добрый день, уже понял в чем ошибка, но не разобрался, как удалить вопрос.

Comment: Но все равно спасибо, что уделили внимание моему вопросу)

Comment: Я бы вам советовал убрать цикл по j, в нем в таком виде нет смысла, только усложняет код